# How to create and compare syrupy snapshots in hypothesis's stateful testing?

Tags: python, testing, python-hypothesis, property-based-testing, snapshot-testing

I want to create a `hypothesis.stateful.RuleBasedStateMachine` to run [stateful testing](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/stateful.html) in Python. When the test is running, I want it to be deterministic and either update some snapshots or compare with existing, so that I can manually review whether the changes in the snapshot makes sense.

Normally I can use [syrupy](https://github.com/tophat/syrupy)'s `snapshot` assertion fixture to compare and update snapshot files.

Unfortunately, `hypothesis`'s stateful testing does not support fixtures, therefore I cannot directly use the `snapshot` fixture.

What should I do to use `syrupy` with `hypothesis` in stateful testing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to ask `syrupy` to support a non-fixtures interface.  From skimming the source this looks technically pretty reasonable; they're mostly using Pytest as source of configuration and for the neat dev experience that fixtures offer.  Unfortunately I don't see a way to support fixtures for Hypothesis stateful tests.

I'm surprised that stateful testing could be deterministic enough to take a single stable snapshot; even in deterministic mode we usually run many diverse inputs.  Perhaps stateful testing isn't offering you much value here?